# $H_1$ and $H_2$ normal subgroups of $G$, $f(g)=(gH_1, gH_2)$ and $G.C.D.(|G/H_1|,|G/H_2|)=1$ then $f$ is epimorphism

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-homomorphism

Let $H_1$ and $H_2$ be normal subgroups of $G$, we define the function $f:G \to G/H_1 \times G/H_2$, $f(g)=(gH_1, gH_2)$. If |G/H_i| is finite $i=1,2$ and $G.C.D.(|G/H_1|,|G/H_2|)=1$ then $f$ is epimorphism.

I have proved that $f$ is homomorphism and the kernel is $H_1 \cap H_2$, I take an arbitrary element $(aH_1,bH_2)$ from $G/H_1 \times G/H_2$ but I don't know how to use that $G.C.D.(|G/H_1|,|G/H_2|)=1$ to prove that there is an element $g \in G$ such that $gH_1=aH_1$ and $gH_1=bH_1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given $a,b\in G$, we want to find $g\in G$ with $g\mapsto(aH_1,bH_2)$.

We know $a\mapsto (aH_1,aH_2)$ and $(|G/H_1|,|G/H_2|)=1$. The order of $aH_1$, $|aH_1|$, divides $|G/H_1|$ and $|aH_2|$ divides $|G/H_2|$ so $(|aH_1|,|aH_2|)=1$ and there exist integers $x,y$ with $x|aH_1|+y|aH_2|=1$.

Let $N=y|aH_2|=1-x|aH_1|$. Then $a^N\mapsto(aH_1,H_2)$.

Similarly there exists an integer $M$ with $b^M\mapsto(H_1,bH_2)$. Hence $a^Nb^M\mapsto(aH_1,bH_2)$.

Comment: In paragraph 2 there is a $bH_2$ that should be $aH_2$, everything else is fine. Also, how do I generalize this when there are more than two normal subgroups $H_1,H_2,...,H_r$ such that $G.C.D.(|G/H_i|,|G,H_j|)=1$ ?

Comment: Ok the general case follows from your proof, given $(a_1 H_1, a_2 H_2, \cdots, a_r H_r)$ we want to find $g \in G$ such that $g \mapsto (a_1 H_1, a_2 H_2, \cdots, a_r H_r)$. From the previous proof we know that for every pair $i, j \in \{ 1, 2, \cdots, r  \}$ there is an integer $N_{ij}$ such that $a_i^{N_{ij}} H_i = a_i H_i$ and $a_i^{N_{ij}} H_j = H_j$, then $a_1^{\prod_{j \neq 1} N_{1j}  } \cdots a_r^{\prod_{j \neq r} N_{rj}  }   \mapsto   (a_1 H_1, a_2 H_2, \cdots, a_r H_r)$.

Comment: That looks correct, and very neatly put!